# why camera output is returned as a low resolution quality?

Tags: android, image-processing, android-camera

Hey guys I have a question about output after taking picture. I have these codes

```
private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1337;



Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

Actually, I tried to use

```
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, 
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
```

But the output is still the same so, anyone can solve this problem for me 
it would be great if you post example codes :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

this should be a camera parameters `setPictureSize(int , int)` method

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html